# NodeJS + ReactJS ES6 compatibility

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-services, hybrid-mobile-app

For our current app we am developing a mobile app in reactJS with ES6. Initially  we were planned to deployed it as stand alone client app latter to resolve few dependency we have to deploy it as server application wrapped in  NodeJS. Now we are facing issue as NodeJS is not supporting ES6 as of now. Also we are all developed with reactJS app so not in condition to change the Arch of app. So is there is any work around for it so that we can use NodeJS with reactJS ES6

Thanks In advance... :)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using NVM for managing multiple dependencies. For ReactJS you can use es6 and for Node project you can use older node version. Please visit : [Link to NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

You can read detailed tutorial  [here](https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/working-with-multiple-nodejs-versions-85c8eef7a600)